# Does the Blender Game Engine support mobile platforms?

Tags: game-engine

Can BGE games be built for mobile platforms? (Android/iOS)? If not, is support planned?

Comment: You may also want to look at [gamekit](https://code.google.com/p/gamekit/) as an alternative.

Comment: In addition to gamekit, Unity is really popular for creating android and iOS games with blender models, but it is really expensive.

Comment: @J.A.Streich i have looked into unity and as you said expensive... i try to stick to open source software as much as i can.  i dont see any reason why blender doesn't become the open source alternative to unity ... or better yet, everything... i would love to see blenders feature set expand beyond its current intended functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently out of the box, there is no support. Work has been done to port blender to android, link [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/Android), [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Android/Building_Blender_for_Android), and [here](http://www.blendernation.com/2012/06/26/blenderplayer-for-android/). You will have to build a mobile version yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Blender for Android is only the player.  I would still use my full size Linux box with a touchscreen.  Then test it on a Android device (1 GB RAM).  However, the power as time goes on, the smart phone might be able to support Blender of Android: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zj4AmAElqzg

That is going to be fact.  However, I need to be willing to use a expensive smartphone solely as a game development platform.  I am not there yet.